# IP Route Add Issue

Tags: ip, routing, loopback

I'm trying to set up IE browsing with fixed routes in the route table.

Before adding the static route, I can browse http://www.whatsmyip.org/ with internet explorer

After I add a fixed route e.g.

```
route -p add 208.64.38.55 255.255.255.255 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

internet explorer cant find the page
(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my ip address, my subnet is 255.255.255.240)

The project I'm working on requires webbrowsing using several public IP addresses. Once I get this piece working, I hope to use microsoft loopback adaptor for each IP and batch files to update the route table.

Comment: You got multiple router ? Thus the multiple route ?

Comment: Its a vpn server, theres one physical adaptor

Comment: ok, so you got a router and that vpn router ? if no, only that vpn server, then you just can't as it got one adapter

Comment: Your PC isn't a gateway, it won't respond to requests made for another IP. You can use Natting, but you would still need a router configured to respond to that IP. Seeing as how you've mentioned only webbrowsing, have you looked into using hostfiles?

Comment: "Your PC isn't a gateway, it won't respond to requests made for another IP" - I don't understand - I am adding a static route for the ip that is set in the adaptor

Comment: thanks but hosts no good. So, I can host 3 websites with 3 ips but can only use 1 ip(assigned by the router) for webbrowsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the first hop for the gateway, not your own computer.

The interface used is generally whatever is on the same subnet as the specified gateway. If you want to manually assign one, you can use the "IF " directive at the end, such as "IF 1" or "IF 2".

Answer (score 0):

1) print out your route table.  on windoze this is "route print".  on linux "ip route" or "netstat -nr".

2) look for the default gateway and make sure its correct.  the is "default" or "0.0.0.0"

3) if incorrect, delete is and add correct gateway.  on linux "ip route add default via [gatewayip/netmaskbits] dev [device]".  on windoze, this is something like:

> route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 gateway 192.168.1.3 interface 192.168.1.1 metric 25